# Issue with JSON parsing: "q\r\nq"

Tags: javascript, json, string

I needed to parse some data and pass with the request body,

Data I need to keep in request body contains carriage return/ line change, which is creating a problem when parsing the same,

I don't understand why it cannot be parsed into a JS native object when it's a valid JSON.

```js
let x= "q\r\nq"

let y= "q\\r\\nq"

JSON.parse(x)

JSON.parse(y)
```

as both x and y are the valid JSONs.

Comment: x and y not valid json

Comment: @YasharPanahi a simple string a valid JSON, how x and y are not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your JSON's content doesn't include quotes. Strings in JSON need to be quoted.

This works:

```
>> JSON.parse('"q\\r\\nq"')
"q
q"
```

Comment: Why the quotes are needed?
let x = '21212';
JSON.parse(x)
works well.

what about 
"q\r\nq"

Comment: That would be parsed into a number, not a string

Comment: @Ariz: numbers don't need quotes, strings do. Just like in Javascript.

Comment: thanks @RemcoGerlich but what about 
let x= {y: "q\\r\\nq"}
or let y = '"q\r\nq"'
I still dont get the complete asnwer.

Comment: @Ariz in `let x= {y: "q\\r\\nq"}`, `{y: "q\\r\\nq"}` is not JSON either, it's an object literal. It's already a JS object, it doesn't need parsing. JSON is a text representation of data. Parsing is the act of turning the text into object data which can be used in code. I'm not sure what point you're trying to make here?

Comment: @ADyson sorry about that, '{"y": "q\r\nq"}'

Comment: @Ariz ok well that works because it's parseable as an object containing a single property, whose value is a string. `q\r\nq` by itself is not a string (due to lack of quote marks), and it's not a number (obviously), so it can't be parsed as JSON. Don't confuse (as I did in the comments on the main question above) the quote marks being used to declare a string variable in the JavaScript with the quote marks which form part of the JSON string itself.

Comment: @Ariz ...cont'd: What gets parsed by JSON.parse is what's _within_ the outer quotes i.e. the content of the string, not including those quote marks themselves, which are used to mark the start and end of the string to the JS compiler. If, in a more realistic scenario, it was parsing JSON returned from an AJAX request there would be no outer quotes, because the data is not being hard-coded into a JS string - that's only done here for the purpose of making a simple demonstration.

Comment: @ADyson I am not sure if the issue is only quotes as
'{"a": "qq"}' and '{"y": "q\\r\\nq"}' can be parsed but
'{"y": "q\r\nq"}' cannot.
or I am still missing something?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182849/discussion-between-ariz-and-adyson).

Answer (score 1):

Add quotes:

```
JSON.parse('"q\\r\\nq"')
```

Answer (score -1):

Use a real JSON

```
let x= "{\"value\": \"q\\r\\nq\"}"
JSON.parse(x)
```

Comment: And this is irrelevant really, because OP is trying to deal with the data they've actually got, not some data you made up

Comment: you can delete your answer if you feel it's no longer relevant